# Show that $h$ is invertible over its entire image

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f:A→B$ and $g:C→D$ be two bijections. Consider the function $$h=(f,g): A×C→B×D$$
My question is: Show that $h$ is invertible over its entire image.

Comment: What would the inverse probably be? Show that it is indeed the inverse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** A function is a bijection iff it has an inverse.

Use the fact that $f,g$ are bijections and find an inverse for $h$